# Java BufferedReader to String Array

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, filereader, filewriter

I was looking through a lot of diffrent subjects here on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything helpful so far :/

So this is my problem. I am writing a filecopier. The problem occurs already at reading the file. My test docoument got 3 lines of random text. All those 3 lines should get written in a string array. The problem is that only the 2nd line of the textdocument gets written in the array and I can't figure out why. Already debugged it, but didn't get me any further.

I know there are diffrent solutions for a filecopier with diffrent classes etc. But I would really like to get it running with the classes I used here.

```
    String[] array = new String[5];
    String datei = "test.txt";
    public String[] readfile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(datei);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
    try {
        int i=0;
        //String  Zeile = bf.readLine();
        while(bf.readLine() != null){
            array[i] = bf.readLine();
        //  System.out.println(array[i]);  This line is for testing
            i++;
        }
        bf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're calling `readLine()` twice for each iteration of the loop, thereby discarding every other line. You need to capture the value returned by *every* call to `readLine()`, because each `readLine()` call advances the reader's position in the file.

Here's the [idiomatic](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.java#116) solution:

```
String line;
while((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
    array[i] = line;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast and very helpful answer ! Everything works perfectly now. Would upvote and mark as the best answer, if I had any reputation.

Comment: By accepting the answer, you did exactly that `:)` and if you really feel like you need to upvote as well, you can always come back later when you have sufficient rep.

Answer (score 1):

Here you read 2 lines:

```
   while(bf.readLine() != null){
        array[i] = bf.readLine();
    //  System.out.println(array[i]);  This line is for testing
        i++;
    }
```

You have to change your Code to:

```
   String line = null;
   while((line =bf.readLine()) != null){
        array[i] = line;
    //  System.out.println(array[i]);  This line is for testing
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
while(bf.readLine() != null)
```

`readLine()` reads a line and returns the same at the same time it moves to the next line.

So instead of just checking if the returned value was `null` also store it.

```
String txt = null;
while((txt = bf.readLine()) != null)
    array[i++] = txt;
```

Comment: Instead of giving me the 3 lines of my test file, it gives me 3 lines that say "null". The problem is already solved but I want to learn as much as possible. Would be glad if we could get your solution working, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are calling readLine() twice. First time in the loop, and then second time when you put it in the array. So, it reads a line at the beginning of the loop (line 1), then first line of code inside the loop (line 2 that you see)

Answer (score -1):

I am use Stream.

**Not a. This form only applies to reading text files.**

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
// ...
List<String> lines = bf.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```